# bootstrap-datepicker.js file issue after saving

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am having problem with bootstrap-datepicker.js. I am trying to change default date format. After changing it and saving the file, The changing is no reflected on the page. When I check the page source on the website, the value is still the same as default. On the other hand, when I open the file the vaue is saved as I want.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

My Values:

```
var defaults = $.fn.datepicker.defaults = {
    autoclose: true,     <============ My Value
    beforeShowDay: $.noop,
    calendarWeeks: false,
    clearBtn: false,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [],
    endDate: Infinity,
    forceParse: true,
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', <============ My Value
    keyboardNavigation: true,
    language: 'en',
    minViewMode: 0,
    multidate: false,
    multidateSeparator: ',',
    orientation: "auto",
    rtl: false,
    startDate: -1,
    startView: 0,
    todayBtn: false,
    todayHighlight: true,
    weekStart: 0
};
```

Page Source Values:

```
var defaults = $.fn.datepicker.defaults = {
    autoclose: false,   <============ Default Value
    beforeShowDay: $.noop,
    calendarWeeks: false,
    clearBtn: false,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [],
    endDate: Infinity,
    forceParse: true,
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',   <============ Default Value
    keyboardNavigation: true,
    language: 'en',
    minViewMode: 0,
    multidate: false,
    multidateSeparator: ',',
    orientation: "auto",
    rtl: false,
    startDate: -Infinity,
    startView: 0,
    todayBtn: false,
    todayHighlight: false,
    weekStart: 0
};
```

Comment: You are probably writing the wrong file, getting some cached code or have some error in your gulp script. Many explainations are possible....Please be more specific

Comment: I have checked the file I am writing so many times. The file is the same file. It may be the cached code.